# Feeds Import stuck after cron

Tags: 7, feeds, cron

Each time cron runs automatically, Feeds import skips half the new feeds and 2 out of 4 feed importers gets always stuck. E.g.:

[image]

Solves by Unlocking, but I can't keep clicking Unlock after each cron everyday. Also, max feed count is 500 overall.

4 feeds using XPath XML parser to import feeds from 4 xml pages from one Drupal site. Those two that get stuck, has per 200 feeds each, the other 2 are fine, they are like 10 feeds max. Also after Unlocking the stuck import, it shows it 'imported' ~200 feeds for example, but actually it didn't, because they don't exist in Content list. Also, all these 200 are already imported manually from before, so why would it try to reimport feeds that exist and get stuck? Also I am using Title as Unique to protect from duplicates.

Importing feeds manually each per feed importer works perfect, but hourly cron runs are not.

Skip Hash Check unchecked.

Dblog:

> Notice: Undefined index: start_time in FeedsSource->import() (line 369 of sites/all/modules/feeds/includes/FeedsSource.inc)

Comment: Do you have 'skip hash check' ticked by any chance?  We ran into some server load issues because it was attempting to update every single node each time regardless of whether it changed (we had like 3000 nodes though)

Comment: It's unticked. Do I have to tick it?

Comment: No, it's more processing intensive when it's ticked.

Comment: Nothing in the dblog?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: start_time in FeedsSource->import() (line 369 of sites/all/modules/feeds/includes/FeedsSource.inc)

Comment: Hmmm, just a notice so doesn't seem like something that should stop the import.

Comment: You never know though, it might be the problem. I can't think of a reason why a start_time wouldn't be logged.